# Return the column value that common among multiple rows meeting criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of schedules, and each schedule must have 1 or more associated criteria. The parent and child look like this:

```
SchedId ScheduleName
1       ScheduleA
2       ScheduleB
3       ScheduleC
```

Criteria table:

```
CriteriaName    CriteriaValue    SchedId
color           red              1
width           wide             1
depth           verydeep         1
color           blue             2
density         dense            3
height          short            3
porosity        spongy           3
```

Now, I have data records for which I need to identify the correct schedule. Because my query is restricted to a particular domain, I happen to know exactly which criteria to test for--in other words I know I'm interested only in results where there are exactly 3 criteria involved, and I know they are color, width and depth.

A typical data record set might look like:

```
Color        Width       Depth
--------------------------------------
red          narrow      shallow
red          medium      deep
blue         wide        verydeep
red          wide        verydeep
```

I also happen to know that there is 1 and only 1 schedule having a given set of values for the known criteria. So what could be easier?

Conceptually my desired query looks like:

```
SELECT color, width, depth, SchedId
  FROM [...]
```

and a correct return row would be:

```
red     wide     verydeep    1
```

I've used the answer to a similar problem here to get the desired SchedId in at least two different ways--one by JOINing selects on the criteria table for each set of criteria (criterianame = color, criteriavalue = red), joining on the SchedId requiring the SchedId for all returned rows to be the same. This works because I used literal values in the query.

I can find no way, in a regular query (no sproc) to get the values of my data rows to the JOIN subselects for use in comparison.

The other technique I've used in the past for this exact problem is one I'm trying to avoid--it basically counts the number of matches I get on the criteria for each SchedId. If the number of matches for a given SchedId equals the number of criteria for that Id, then it's the correct Sched. I don't much care for that approach, although it's worked okay. This technique was used with MySQL, but I am now using T-SQL.

Finallly, I designed the criteria table this way to allow unlimited numbers of criteria, and unlimited kinds of criteria for an unlimited number of schedules. It has proven to be amazingly challenging. Ideas?

Comment: I think you would like to perform a dynamic cross-tab query. That's not easy to do in SQL Server, but [it is possible](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#Crosstab).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using conditional aggregation:

```
select pt.Schedid, pt.schedname,
       max(case when ct.citerianame = 'color' then ct.criteriavalue end) as Color, 
       max(case when ct.citerianame = 'width' then ct.criteriavalue end) as Width, 
       max(case when ct.citerianame = 'depth' then ct.criteriavalue end) as Depth
from parenttbl pt inner join
     criteriatbl ct
     on pt.schedid = ct.schedid
group by pt.schedid, pt.schedname;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    case when ct.citerianame = 'color' then ct.criteriavalue end Color, 
    ,case when ct.citerianame = 'width' then ct.criteriavalue end Witdh, 
    ,case when ct.citerianame = 'depth' then ct.criteriavalue end Depth
    ,pt.Schedid  


FROM 
    parenttbl pt 
    inner join criteriatbl ct on pt.schedid = ct.schedid
where 
    pt.schedid = 1
```